# Output to the screen without moving to a new line

Tags: c#

**Console.WriteLine** automatically move text on a new line and I have output on the console like:

```
1
2
3
4

5
..
```

But I need:

```
1234
5..
```

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)         
        Console.WriteLine(aField[i, j]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to write a *line*, don't use `Console.Write*Line*`. Just use [`Console.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(aField[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

(Note that your sample output only contains four characters, whereas your inner loop has 5 iterations. I'm hoping this is just a sample discrepancy, and nothing more complicated.)